# JSP file is not rendering in Spring-Boot after included dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I am creating simple demo Spring boot application. I have included all required dependencies in pom.xml file for jsp and set in application.properties as well but still not working.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project
```

> 

controller.java

```
package com.example.demoController;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class controller {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String first() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

[here is the project directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJSdn.png)

please suggest something to resolve this problem.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to hit and what is the response or error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSP file should be in by default "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp" directory and right now it seems to be in wrong location.

***UPDATE***:- Looking at your shared code - the reason you are facing this problem is that you have annotated your Controller with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` because of which the String you are returning from your controller is being written directly on the output stream instead of framework first checking the view name against a JSP template and then rendering it. If you change the annotation to @Controller it works fine

Comment: yes i also tried this and follow below process as well but still not working.
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic.html

it only showing the string name that controller returning.

Comment: Can you post your code on github and share ?

Comment: https://github.com/RAshutosh12/firstweb

please help to check.

Comment: Please check the update in answer. And don't forget to mark this answer accepted - as a correct practice on SO :-)